# How to get const_iterator when the T is 'const std::map',?

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

I have the following struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo 
{
  typename T::iterator iter;
};
```

The expected type:

- `iter` is a `std::map<K, V>::iterator` when `T` is deduced as `std::map<K, V>`.
- `iter` is a `std::map<K, V>::const_iterator` when `T` is deduced as `const std::map<K, V>`

But my code always get a `std::map<K, V>::iterator`.

How to achieve the expected implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide a [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) type:

```
#include <type_traits>  // std::conditional_t

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  using iter = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>
               , typename T::const_iterator
               , typename T::iterator>;
};
```